# Spoof hardware serial numbers?

Tags: windows, spoofing

Here's what happened, I play MTA-SA(Multiplayer San Andreas Game) and got banned of an online server. I still want to play on the same server however, so I tried changing my IP - didn't work, I tried re-installing MTA - didn't work, I tried re-installing with my hardware serials spoofed using an app called PB Downforce 0.2 - didn't work yet.

Since all that MTA when banning is to store the hardware serial/IP/username - I tried changing all but so far it hasn't work. And I suspect that the hardware-spoof tool that I'm using maybe it fault for if it is indeed working as it should(and properly), then I should be able to bypass the ban on the server, no? Or is it that MTA stores some other info too to identify the banned person?

Is there any other way or tool that you guys know that does hardware-spoofing or can get me around solving this problem?

Here's the tool that I used for hardware-spoofing - PB Downforce 0.2

Please help and thanks in advance to anyone who does.

Answer (score 6):

1. You got banned.
2. Your serial, IP address and username are banned (and most likely, some unique hash generated from your MAC address, etc)
3. You tried connecting from a new IP.
4. That new IP got banned, because you still used other banned information.
5. You *spoofed your hardware serials* and connected again.
6. Now even more information is banned.

Instead of trying to gain access to this server, you should take a time out and reflect on your behavior.

Comment: Haha, you made up a lot of things actually. I got banned just once(because I killed the admin of that server on DM, how silly, no?). I tried spoofing my IP, Hardware serials and username to get in and give that admin a piece of his mind. What I have to know here is what exactly is it MTA remembers about a banned person, now I no it's not just IP, Hardware serial or username or maybe the tool I used didn't work properly? Also there must be a way to change my MAC address, I guess.